# Do combinatory logic bases need a function of 3 variables?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, lambda-calculus

All the known bases of combinatory logic, such as $\{S,K\}$, or $\{K,W,B,C\}$,
have one or more combinators using 3 variables:
\begin{align*}
S ={} & \lambda x\lambda y\lambda z. x z(y z), \\
B ={} & \lambda x\lambda y\lambda z. x  (y z), \\
C ={} & \lambda x\lambda y\lambda z. x   z y.
\end{align*}
This raises the question whether we can make a basis with functions of only 2 variables. Surely if such a thing were possible, it would be a most interesting result and it would be well-known.
But as far as I can tell, no such thing is known. Thus it seems nobody believes such a thing to be possible.

But has this been proven anywhere?

How do we know that $\{K,W,2,O,T,D\}$ is not a basis, where
\begin{align*}
K ={} & \lambda x\lambda y. x, \\
W ={} & \lambda x\lambda y. x y y, \\
2 ={} & \lambda f\lambda x. f(f x), \\
O ={} & \lambda x\lambda y. y(x y), \\
T ={} & \lambda x\lambda y. y x, \\
D ={} & \lambda x. x x?
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't know how many variables one counts the [$\iota$ combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_and_Jot#Universal_iota) $\iota = \lambda f. (f S)K$ as having.

Comment: it has 4 nested lambdas, so let's call it 4.

Comment: @LSpice: The definition I’m familiar with, used e.g. in the Legrand paper [Peter Taylor’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415338/2273) and [mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415373/2273) are based on, is that a *combinator of rank $n$* is one with a reduction rule $C x_1 \ldots x_n \to E$ where $E$ is formed just from $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and application.  So more complex combinators like the universal $\iota$ don’t fit that form.  It would be nice to have a more general definition of rank that extended Legrand’s result to cover $\iota$ and similar, but I’ve not come across such a definition.

Comment: I learned that a very similar result was proved for lambda calculus; see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36276/incomplete-basis-of-combinators/

Comment: Thanks to @JohnTromp for linking the related cstheory question from here and vice versa.  I did not know about Remi Legrand's paper.  Indeed, Rick Statman also has a self-contained paper "Two variables are not enough" (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2100917) proving a slightly stronger result, that any complete basis of closed lambda terms must contain a term with at least 3 distinct bound variables.  The idea of the proof is contained in his earlier 1988 tech report on "Combinators hereditarily of order two" (https://doi.org/10.1184/R1/6477068.v1).

Comment: Just a comment about generalizing the definition of "rank" of a combinator (@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine).  As per the papers by Statman, considering a combinator as a closed lambda term, one can talk about the minimum number of distinct bound variables needed to represent it.  And as per my cstheory answer, that can be equivalently (but I find slightly more cleanly) expressed as the maximum number of free variables in any subterm of the combinator.  Under either of those equivalent definitions of "rank" (or "hereditary rank"), the $\iota$ combinator has rank 4, as per @JohnTromp's suggestion.

Comment: Under those definitions of rank, the  combinator has rank 3, not 4. In fact, use of the tuple operator <A1,...Ak> = x.x A1 ... Ak never increases the rank above any Ai, which can freely re-use variable x.

Comment: thanks, yes, you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 26):

[*A Basis Result in Combinatory Logic*](https://doi.org/10.2307/2274616), Remi Legrand, J. Symb. Logic 53.4 (1988), pp. 1224-1226.

> The aim of this article is to show that a basis for combinatory logic must contain at least one combinator with rank strictly greater than two.

Answer (score 18):

[@PeterTaylor’s excellent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415338/2273) points to exactly the result wanted.  But the proof there can be streamlined a bit, and may be paywalled for some readers, so I’ll write it out here for accessibility.

**Theorem.** Let $\newcommand{\B}{\mathbf{B}}\B$ be any set of combinators of rank ≤2.  Then there is no $\B$-expression $T$ such that $\newcommand{\reddto}{\twoheadrightarrow}Tabc \reddto cab$.

**Proof.**  Fix such $\B$ throughout.  The idea is (unsurprisingly) to find an invariant of $Tabc$ that is sufficiently closed under reduction, and not satisfied by $cab$.  Say that an expression is *bad* if it is of the form $E[F[a,b],c]$, where $E$ and $F$ are each $\B$-expressions of 2 variables.  Then we have:

**Lemma.** Any bad expression is either normal, or else has a reduction chain to another bad expression, including at least one leftmost reduction.

**Proof of lemma.** If a bad expression $E[F[a,b],c]$ is not stuck, consider its leftmost redex.  There are three possible cases:

1. The head combinator of the redex is not in an occurrence of $F$.  Then each occurrence of $F$ is either outside the redex, or inside an argument of the head combinator; so the reduct is of the form $E'[F[a,b],c]$.
2. The whole redex is inside an occurrence of $F$.  Then by reducing it in *every* occurrence of $F$, we have $E[F[a,b],c] \reddto E[F'[a,b],c]$, and this includes the leftmost redex.
3. The head combinator $H$ is iside an occurrence of $F$, but not the whole redex.  Then $H$ must be of rank ≥1.  If $H$ is of rank 1, then $F$ is just $H$, so $x,y$ don’t occur, and the whole expression (both before and after reduction) is of the form $E'[c]$, so is still bad.  If the head combinator is of rank 2, then we must have $F[a,b] \equiv HF'[a,b]$, so by re-parsing as $E[F[a,b],c] \equiv E'[F'[a,b],c]$, case 1 applies.

This proves the lemma. It follows that any bad expression either reduces to a bad normal form, or has an infinite quasi-leftmost reduction sequence.  So by the quasi-leftmost-reduction theorem (Hindley–Seldin 2008, Thm 3.22), any normal form of a bad expression is bad; and so the bad expression $Tabc$ cannot reduce to the normal, non-bad expression $cab$. □

References:

- Rémi Legrand, *A Basis Result in Combinatory Logic*, J. Symb. Logic 1988; [jstor full text](https://doi.org/10.2307/2274616)
- J. Roger Hindley, Jonathan P. Seldin, *Lambda-Calculus and Combinators, an Introduction*, CUP 2008